# where are the auto generated routes in rails scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright, I'm starting to learn rails and so far im really turned off by how much is auto generated and happening behind the scenes without me knowing. I generated scaffolding for posts. and it auto created routes allowing me to edit and see posts (/posts, /posts/:id/edit, /posts/:id/show....etc) When I go into config/routes.rb I see absolutely no mention of these routes. even though they work. Where are these routes? and where can I add custom routes if the ones for the controller are not in routes.rb?

Comment: You might like Sinatra if you like writing all your own stuff. http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Comment: They should be there. Are you sure you're checking routes for the same project you created scaffold for? (BTW, you are looking for `resources :posts`)

Comment: I see resources :posts, it still doesnt explain where the specific routes are

Comment: @JakeSchievink - Those are your routes. `resources` is a method which generates all the RESTful paths you need. Routing in rails is the very reason I hated rails for my first 3 months with it. Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: Rails does do a lot of magic and it was hard at first for me to know what was going on. It is also magic that caused a big security hole (Ooh rails parses XML requests for my plain ole controller, and executes embedded YAML code callouts. Where is that listed?!)

Comment: @Cereal sinatra looks incredible, such simple syntax, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you run `rails generate scaffold post`, rails will generate models, controllers, tests, routes, stylesheets etc.
   Rails tells you what files it just generated, you can see it in terminal.
   In *routes.rb* there will be a line 
   *resources :post*, this is a shorthand for all RESTful actions that were generated in the controller.
2. You can declare custom routes in the *routes.rb* file. I.e.:

   get 'my_path'=> 'my_controller#my_action'

In General, Rails can do a lot of stuff for you, and you can avoid repeating default behaviour over and over again. But you can also do most stuff yourself, without Rails magic.
Instead of using scaffolds, just run `rails generate controller controller_name action1 action2 (..)`. You'll end up with just a controller, no automatic views, no automatic model etc.
Or you can just create all files and register your components yourself. 
The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are a good starting point for understanding the magic.